# Redirect URL to another Rewritten URL

Tags: regex, .htaccess, joomla

I am using the built in Joomla/Virtuemart SEF options on my website. What I am looking to do is redirect `http://www.uniqbuy.com/electronics/component/virtuemart/`
to
`http://www.uniqbuy.com/electronics/store-product-categories.html`

The second URL is itself a rewritten URL if that makes a difference. But, I am very stuck. Can anyone help? I would post what I have tried so far, but I do not have enough reputation to post more than 2 links.

Comment: .htaccess and turn rewritemodule on in Apache?

Comment: Try to code quote the URLs or write them relative to the root of the domain. And if you want to post your redirect rules, write them in your question directly (instead of linking).

Comment: Thanks, should have given more info.

I am trying to do the redirect in .htaccess and server does support it. I am just not too sure about the code to use. 

I tried:
RewriteRule ^http://www.uniqbuy.com/electronics/store-product-categories.html$ http://www.uniqbuy.com/electronics/component/virtuemart/ [L]

But, that didn't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try any of these http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/url-redirection .

I think these may be useful to you.